# My wife is from the UK, I'd like to visit with her and work

Tags: united-kingdom, australian-citizens

I'm from Australia and my wife and I are planning on settling in Australia so we live here, she is going back to the UK for 6 months and id like to go with her and work for that time.
Is there any visas for that purpose more specifically?

Comment: There are no visit visas that would allow you to work unless you happen to be an artist or entertainer/performer https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: Are you under 30?

Comment: Like @MJeffryes said. If you you're under 30 and meet some other criteria then you can apply for this https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility as an Australian citizen

Comment: You could also apply for a spousal settlement visa, but that's a rather expensive undertaking for six months' work.